# Adding small-extent rasters to DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

My goal: create viewsheds for observers which also incorporate the heights of buildings which could block observer view. This is using archaeological data, and is representing time change -- so I need to make several versions of the DEM, representing different periods of time when particular buildings would be erect or torn down.

I made raster files representing the extent and height of each building. They're really simple -- just rectangles with a single height. I used the Mosaic to New Raster tool to add three building rasters to a single raster file. Then, I used Mosaic to New Raster again, and added the collective building raster to the DEM (7806x9732) -- when I initially tested this using three buildings and the DEM, it worked fine.

Now, I am running into issues of the tool crashing with non-tested material. I've tried mosaicing each individual building (e.g. DEM + Building 1, DEM and Building 1 + Building 2, etc.) and it crashes. I've remade some building files to check and make sure they aren't corrupt.

I've tried a Con is Null statement as well, and it's crashing:

```
Con(IsNull("BUILDING"), "DEM", "DEM"+"BUILDING")
```

I'm getting 999999 errors. Or ArcMap just quits.

Any ideas?

If it's a memory issue, I'm willing to use the polygon version of the extents as well -- all I really need to do is change the values of the DEM within small rectangular areas - adding the height of the building to the DEM.

Comment: So is the DEM you are using the same DEM that worked previously? Are your new buildings in a different coordinate system to the DEM? Show us how you set up the mosaic tool to mosaic DEM and buildings, this should be an easy operation.